# Index was out of range c# when checking against AD

Tags: c#, sql, indexoutofrangeexception

When checking the user against active directory, I also check their mail attribute try to store it into a session variable

However, when the users AD account doesn't have a mail address, I would like to display this on the screen for them.

At the moment an exception is caught for index out of range

How can I can check for this so that I can set the label property?  I obviously want to avoid setting it in the catch.

```
         try
            {
                var mail = adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"][0] ;
                if (mail == null)
                {
                    Label3.Text = "blablabla";
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["email"] = adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString().ToLower();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
              Response.Write(ex); 
            }
```

Comment: what can't you check var mail = adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"] first? if it isnt null then you can check the count property instead of indexing it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply could add null and length check, you should actually if there is such possibility.

```
try {
  if (adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"]!= null && adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"].Any()) {
      var mail = adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"][0];
      if (mail == null) {
          Label3.Text = "blablabla";
          return;
      } else {
          Session["email"] = adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString()
              .ToLower();
      }
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Response.Write(ex);
}
```